# Pig Latin Code in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python, and I want my code to move the first one or two consonants to the end of the word and add -ay. I have gotten my code to do this but it doesn't work for sentences. I need help with the list. Also, the returned, translated sentence needs to start with an uppercase letter and end with a period, just like the input sentence but I have no clue where to start with this! Here is my code so far:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a sentence:')
word = original.lower()
word_list = word.split
count = 0

for word in word_list:
if word[1] == "a" or word[1] == "e" or word[1] == "i" or word[1] == "u" or 
word[1] == "o" or word[1] == "y":
  first = word[0]
  new_word = word + first + pyg
  new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
  print new_word 

else:  
 if word[1] != "a" or word[1] != "e" or word[1] != "i" or word[1] != "u" or 
word[1] != "o" or word[1] != "y":
    first = word[0]
    second = word[1]
    second_word = word + first + second + pyg
    second_word = second_word[2:len(second_word)]
    print second_word
```

Comment: There are a few issues, but you're on the right track with `split` (but you'll need parens -- `split()`).  I'll just point out that you can write your `if` statements as simply: `if word[1] in "aeiouy":` (for the first) and `if word[1] not in "aeiouy":`  Note: the second suggestion changes the function of what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried creating the code using .format() , being beginner myself , I hope you find this code easy & helpful.

```
def pig_latin(text):
 say = ""
 words = text.split()
 for word in words:
  say += "{}{}{} ".format(word[1:], word[0], "ay")
 return say
```

print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))

> ellohay owhay reaay ouyay

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly generalized version of what you say you want. The difference is that the code below doesn't look at the first one or two letters: it shifts *all* initial consonants to the end, so that `string` becomes `ingstray`. Your problem statement says that should be `ringstay`, but that doesn't accord with the Pig Latin I learnt as a child. I've done this partly because I think your specification is incomplete, and partly because it makes the code simpler, and that makes it easier to understand. You can always amend the code if `ringstay` is really what you want. (Hint: put a counter in the `while` loop.) There is also a bug in this code, though you would be unlikely to find it: if an input word contains no vowels at all, for example *cwm* (a kind of Welsh fiddle) then the `while` loop will never terminate. (Hint: same solution.)

I haven't added the refinement, also dimly remembered from my childhood, that an original word that begins with a vowel gets the suffix `way` not `ay`, so `I am good` comes out as `Iway amway oodgay` not `Iay amay oodgay`.

The Pythonic way to do a membership test is to use `in`, not a long string of `if x == 'a' or x == 'b' or x == 'c'` tests.

Providing an initial capital and a final fullstop requires you to split the problem into two: (1) transform the words, and (2) punctuate the sentence. You can't do that if you `print` the transformed words out as you go along. So the code below assembles the words into a `result` list and then strings the list of words into a final sentence for punctuation.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a sentence:')
word_list = original.lower().split()
result = []

for word in word_list:
    while word[0] not in "aeiouy":
        word = word[1:] + word[0]
    word += pyg
    result.append(word)

final_sentence = " ".join(result)
print final_sentence[0].upper() + final_sentence[1:] + "."
```

Personally I consider it not good style to store a sentence in a variable called `word`, especially if the code actually stores a word in that same variable at a later point. So I've amended that too.

*Edit* since it appears my hint wasn't explicit enough:

To limit the number of consonants that get shifted to the end, you need to count them:

```
for word in word_list:
    consonants = 0
    while word[0] not in "aeiouy" and consonants < 2:
        word = word[1:] + word[0]
        consonants += 1
    word += pyg
    result.append(word)
```

To make sure the program isn't put into an infinite loop by a word with no consonants:

```
    while word[0] not in "aeiouy" and consonants < len(word):
```

Comment: Ok thank you! However, what would I do if I wanted to ammend the code to be ringstay instead of ingstray?

Comment: I've done an edit to show you what I meant about putting a counter in the `while` loop.